# Better to list names for various SQL entities in one large table or several small?

Tags: sql, performance

**Slightly tricky SQL question here, explanation below**: It is better to have 10+ small "names" tables, identical in all except to what table their "ID" foreign keys refer to, or to have one large "names" table, in which a varchar column specifies which table the ID column is valid for?

(I know there are similar questions about "one large table or several small", but but none that fits to what I wonder about.)

**Clarification:**
I have an SQL database with about 10+ main tables, and a plethora of connecting tables. As an example, imagine a database with tables "`books`", "`authors`", "`publishers`", "`distributors`", "`artists`", "`characters`" etc.

Each of these books, publishers, artists etc might have **more than one name**, not only because they might have different names in different languages, but also because they might actually have more than one name in the same language. Often, they will have just one, but they might have several. They might have twenty. Hard to know.

**What is the smoothest way of handling this, SQL table-wise?** Having tons of "name" columns in each table (as in, one per language), won't work as there might be more than one title per language (and most of those columns will remain empty anyway).
Some of the options I've thought of:

1. One separate "name" table for each of these tables, that refer to its parent table's ID column. This works, but looks really silly (10+ "_names" tables). And, as all of these tables will have the exact same format, the exact same check constraints, it feels like a serious case of Repeating Oneself. If I need to change some constraint or column specification, I have to do it in 10+ places, maybe more if yet another main table pops up.
2. One large "names" table, with both "table name" and "ID" columns, that contains the names of all things. But I would end up with a quite long list. And since I can't (or don't know how to) let a varchar column refer to a table name as a foreign key, I will miss the foreign key constraint.
3. Consolidate all "books", "publishers" etc tables into a larger table called "Items" or "Things", so that no book can have the same ID as a publisher, and then have a large table with "names" as in example (2). That way, the names tables will have a functional foreign key, but looking at the database will be confusing, as you won't separate a "Book" from a "Publisher" anymore. All connecting tables will just refer to the "Things" table, which will be super prone to erroneous relations.
4. Having one long "name" field for each table, and format it in some way f.ex. "`eng:Donald Duck, fre:Donald, nor:Anders And, swe:Kalle Anka`". This way, I won't have to join with other tables to find the names, but each result will require parsing of this string.

I'm leaning between solution (1) or (2). Having one long list of names feels tidier than have 10+ next-to-identical "names" tables, and it will do a "general search" easier. But I'm worried that a large table will slow down the process of searching, especially with multiple joins that all search through this names table. Imagine there are 1000 of each of these entities, and a median of 2 names per row. Instead of a

```
SELECT NAME FROM BOOK_TITLES WHERE ID=? AND LANG=?
```

from a list of 2,000, I will have a

```
SELECT NAME FROM NAMES WHERE TYPE='BOOK' AND ID=? AND LANG=?
```

from a list of 20,000. And I can't even let "Type+ID+lang" be a primary key, since there can be several titles for the same book in the same language, so I imagine the searches will be quite sub-optimal, in the case of a complex query that searches for a book and should yield a result with names of publishers, artists, characters etc, and all of them will search through this 20,000+ rows-table (and it might be way longer than 20,000 in the end) without any primary keys.

Anyone has any idea on what would be the best solution?

Comment: What is a purpose of `name`? Short description of an entitity. Looking at the `name`, man must understand, which exact record is reffered by it. What is a purpose of having different names for the same record and the same language?

Comment: No other purpose than just reality. It's like "Lord of the Rings" is also known as "LOTR" or even "The Lord of the Rings". In the database I'm working on, it's not common, but it does happen, so the database needs to be able to comply.

If there can only be one name for each language and item, then that could make up the primary key, and would eliminate (some of) the performance worries I have.

Comment: by this way you can enter dirty data. Imagine people will enter by mistake "THe Lord of the Rings", "The lord of the Rings". Book names do not have synonymes, in all databases they have a single name. In the comment, in rare cases you can say, it is known as "something else". You must force not to enter data by mistake. Imagine, which name would you show to the customer in GUI or in the report? The single name will be chosen. All other names - is just an extra information, you could store as a comment, possibibly in a separe table if you meet it very rare.

Comment: For books yes, but books is just an example, and not the database I am working with. The one I am working with, multiple names is something that is uncommon, but not rare, and certainly necessary to keep track of.

I wouldn't gain much on having "surplus" names in a separate table, as I would in any way need to look through this "surplus" table in order to get all the names needed, even if I had a "default" name in the main table.

Of course, entered information must be validated. Dirty data is always an issue, regardless of whether you have single names or multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the identifier from the name.

Use an auto-incremented id (or create your own code, for ease-of-use) for each book/publisher/etc...

Instead of looking for the name, look for the book code and only then get all the associated names.

Ideally, you'd get a request like this

```sql
SELECT B.*,
       N.* -- ideally, you'd pivot here, this is an example
FROM BOOK B
JOIN NAMES ON B.code = N.bookCode
WHERE B.code = 1
```

Have one name table for each type of things (book, publisher, etc...). This is not repeating oneself. This is good database design. You shouldn't need to change a name table unless something went wrong during creation.

So option 1.

You can still create a view that consolidate name values if you need it for searching purpose.

You can't create a primary key on non-unique values, but you could still create an index if you feel that particular field combination will be often used.

Comment: Thanks. I imagined this would be the best option, but it felt weird with having so many tables that were next to identical.
(Also, I assume you mean
`FROM BOOK B JOIN NAMES N ON B.code = N.bookCode`)